# FatalErrorException in routes.php line 20: syntax error, unexpected 'get' (T_STRING)

Tags: laravel-5.1

I have fresh Laravel 5.1 and I get this while following [this guide](https://openclassrooms.com/courses/decouvrez-le-framework-php-laravel/les-entrees-1).

```
FatalErrorException in routes.php line 20:
syntax error, unexpected 'get' (T_STRING)
```

Here is my routes.php:

```
    <?php
    get('/', function() {
    return view('vue1')
});

get('article/{n}', 'ArticleController@show')->where('n', '[0-9]+');



get('article/{n}', function($n) { 
    return view('article')->with('numero', $n); 
})->where('n', '[0-9]+');

get('users', 'UsersController@getInfos');
post('users', 'UsersController@postInfos');
```

How can I solve the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your routes are missing the Route:: facade.
Correct them as the below examples:

```
<?php
Route::get('/', function() {
   return view('vue1')
});
Route::post('users', 'UsersController@postInfos');
```